# Which nations have the best bonus to assist in a conquest victory?

Tags: civilization-5

Which nations have the best bonus to assist in a conquest victory?

Comment: Do you only care about the special power? The unique units are very important too.

Comment: +1 Any question with > 1k Views deserves more than 1 up-vote :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Japan**. While other nations have bonuses that certainly assist in producing an army, or movement of troops, Japan's bonus directly relates to combat. Since you'll be fighting a lot for a conquest victory, your forces will certainly be fighting hurt - and the ability to always fight at full strength certainly makes it the best option.

Comment: So for Japan, all units health is replenished to full at then end of each turn?

Comment: @Dan: No. Normally, units' attack strength decreases when their health is low. For Japanese units, attack strength remains the same regardless of remaining HP.

Answer (score 1):

Japan is the best. However i find the mogal Keshik unit to be very good at taking down city defenses and can help in an early game conquest. Especially since they can move after attacking, so you end up moving in, hitting the city and then moving out of  harms way. 2 or 3 will deplete a cities defenses to allow ground troops to take the city.